# How can I write a function that will log a user in an old system without knowing any username or password?

Tags: sql-injection, credentials

I'm studying Internet Security and I learned something about code injection in older websites (using the string `' OR 1 == 1 //` as a username will log in with any password provided); but what if a password related to a username is stored in the server in a folder with the following path:

```
/userdata/passwords/<username>
```

with credentials that will log me into the system, without knowing any legitimate usernames or passwords?

Furthermore, in the question it's specified that the login system is installed on a computer running an OS, and that this operating system is known to have a file with its version (in this case, 1.0.3) in `/system/version.txt`.

Honestly, I do not know how this last thing can be related to the question, but I hope that someone can help me to understand what could be the right answer and if and how this thing about the system version is related to the answer.

Here is the screenshot of the question of the online test I'm doing:

[image]

Comment: This question boils down to "can you please hack this system for me?" and unfortunately for you that is not why we are here. This question will most likely be closed soon. If you had a clear, specific question we would be happy to help, but as-is this question is too broad and off topic.

Comment: I do not want anything to be hacked, it's a specific question of a test I'm doing for a lesson of Internet Security course! And this is the first question of the test, as it's related to design vulnerabilities. Btw what I'd like to know is how can i embed the password local path in the credentials and which credentials I should use in order to get access to a system where both usernames and passwords are not known. Beyond that I'd like to have some clarifications wether the file containing OS version can be related to it or not.

Comment: To clarify, the other issue is that there simply aren't nearly enough details to answer this. The questions you are asking are very specific to the application. There is no generic "this is how to override the password local path in the credentials" answer. In fact, that question hardly makes sense.

Comment: To try to help you understand, your statement at the beginning that "this magic string let's you log in on old services" is completely false. That is a common SQLi payload but would only work on specific services using specific software in a specific (and incorrect) way. Perhaps this misconception leads you to believe that someone here can give you a string that will let you in? Fortunately it just doesn't work like that

Comment: If this is a test question then this is the worst test ever

Comment: @Dodoytis Why don't I believe you that?

Comment: @ConorMancone I agree, I didn't understand anything on how to do that, that's why I'm askin' for help

Comment: @MechMK1it's not my problem what you believe or not... I just asked for some help to understand what I've to do with that question to answer... and btw if u check in my question I included the screenshot of the first question of the test

Comment: You've got a couple problems here.  The main one is that stack exchange isn't designed to be a forum.  Rather it is a question-answer site that aims to create clear, concise, and answerable questions.  Therefore questions that require explaining large amounts of background to answer aren't going to fit here.  "Too broad" is another reason questions are often closed.  While I appreciate these facts don't help you, it's an important part of how our particular corner of the internet runs.

Comment: Further, there was really no way to answer your question as originally stated.  Now with the actual question at hand it is more answerable (although it is not a very good question, and homework/test questions typically get closed here too).  However I can get you moving tin the right direction.  You're interested in a [directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) and you want to consider this perspective: you want the username to cause the auth system to read a file with contents which you know (which will be the password to use)

Comment: While we can help with homework, we require that you at least attempt to answer it. We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: @schroeder I'm not asking to do my homeworks, I'm just asking for any hint

Comment: You didn't ask for a hint. And even with hints, you need to give us something to hint you toward.

Comment: @ConorMancone Thank for your help, I'm trying to figure out if the credentials could be related to the path of the system version, and to the number of system version (1.0.3) because there's must be a reason why in the question this thing is underlined... most probably the path could be used as username, as in Python I can give as input the command that read the file content; could it be something like this?

Comment: @schroeder yeah most probably I thought that this website (as it can't be called FORUM), was here to help people who need some hint in their questions... and most probably I was wrong... anyway I appreciate all the kind people that gave me any hint... I won't bother you anymore

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the information that you have been provided with, the question relates to LFI (local file inclusion).
Apparently the credentails are stored on the filesystem (/userdata/passwords/).

The question seems to be ***unrelated*** to the topic that you have been researching, which is SQL injection. The latter would only be an option if the credentials were stored in a DB, which is obviously not the case.

In order to proceed, I'd recommend you to gather all the information that you can get from your question, and research *LFI*.
Once you have found the LFI vulnerability, read /system/version.txt (as part of your enumeration, this might give you more insight into further attack vectors) and try to read /userdata/passwords/ (or bruteforce files within that folder) and you'll have a chance to get user credentials.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm sorry if I tagged it in the wrong way. I read soemthing about LFI, and what I realized is that for example instead of writing something like: https://example-site.com/?module=contact.php, I could write https://example-site.com/?module=/userdata/passwords, and get the list of passwords... but the question is, if I'm in front of a module that asks me for a username and a password, how can I embed these paths in the credentials in a way that using such credentials I can access the reserved area?

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a look at the html source of the page. There, find all _input_ tags within the _form_ (even the hidden ones). Use their _name_ and _value_ attributes for potential LFI attacks. For example, if you have the input attribute names _username_, _password_ and _language_, each of these will be a candidate for LFI.